# Piece identification (Sphere)

Tags: technic, part-identification, fll

I was wondering if [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CXI0.jpg) LEGO piece is a valid LEGO, and what is its part number?
Can it be used in *FIRST* LEGO League competitions?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think this IS a LEGO piece? Does it have any LEGO markings, or connections with other LEGO elements?

Comment: Well, the red piece is for sure a LEGO piece and fits perfectly with the transparent one. Maybe is a piece made by some third-party company. Can it be?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like there are three individual pieces.

1. A small metal ball (Probably not LEGO)
2. A translucent connector (Probably not LEGO)
3. A red [LEGO Technic Cross Axle (6538)](http://brickset.com/parts/4125189)

[image]

The red piece seems to share the same amount of ridges ridges (three) and seems to be a good match in size and colour. I'm not familiar with this connector being used in this manner, I'm fairly sure the other two pieces are not LEGO.

Comment: Seems legit... Good eyesight!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe the other two pieces are made by third-party companies and thus are not official LEGO pieces. So these two pieces can't be used in FLL competitions...?

Comment: I've found a store which sells this item: http://www.mindsensors.com/ev3-and-nxt/88-ball-caster-to-mount-on-nxt-robots. Definitely, it is not an official LEGO piece, so I assume it cannot be used in FLL competitions